# javac: package org.apache.derby.client.am does not exist

Tags: java, javac, derby, javadb

I'm trying to compile a java program that is using JavaDB/Derby. On the command line I can run

```
java org.apache.derby.tools.sysinfo
```

without errors, but the following line in several of the files causes the error in my question title:

```
import org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException;
```

causes

```
package org.apache.derby.client.am does not exist
```

I've done a fresh installation of JavaDB, but I don't think that matters. I've compiled this project once before, and I KNOW I didn't have JavaDB installed. I just had a directory at the top level of the project folder called lib with all of derby's .jar files inside. And I'm pretty sure I didn't have to set any environment variables either.

How can I fix this error? If I need to provide any more information, I will be happy to do so.

I'm using Windows 7 and jdk1.7

Comment: Need to fix the question. Since the error is in javac, the java command is irrelevant. Check your classpath and if it still  doesn't wokr, show the exact javac command.

Comment: `javac` needs to know where to look to find that package. You can specify it by setting the classpath. or using the `-cp` option

Comment: Why are you trying to import the Derby version of SqlException. Perhaps you can just import java.sql.SqlException instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have an issue with the JavaDB JARs not being on your classpath.  Make sure you specify them using `-cp` or `-classpath` on your `javac` command.

Comment: If the files that need to be compiled are in com/company/project and the derby .jar files in lib (both relative to current directory), what should the -cp arg look like? I tried the following:

javac -cp lib;com\company\project com\company\project\*.java


javac -cp com\company\project com\company\project\*.java


javac -cp lib com\company\project\*.java

Comment: You would need to list each jar file separated by a semicolon (if you are on Linux/UNIX you would use a colon) So, you would do: javac -cp lib\jarFileName1.jar;lib\jarFileName2.jar com\company\project\*.java

Comment: I don't know the names of the specific JARs needed by JavaDB, but you should list them all instead of jarFileName1.jar and jarFileName2.jar

Comment: I did. Sorry, I should have replied, but had a lot of work to do. I tried using a wildcard to specify all of the .java files (-cp lib/*), but got an error saying derbyclient.java was an invalid flag. So I tried just derbyclient.java (-cp lib/derbyclient.java) and it worked.

Comment: From my experience wildcards don't really work there.  Glad it helped.